# convert multi-line script to a single statement

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am using the following script to get the start numbers from the output.
Which is working fine as shown below with multiple lines of script.

```
openssl asn1parse -inform der -in $1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1 > outfile.txt
startnum=$(cat outfile.txt | cut -f1 -d:)
echo "startnum:$startnum"
```

**contents of outfile.txt:**

> 7430:d=7  hl=2 l=  11 prim: OBJECT            :id-smime-aa-pattern
> 7567:d=7  hl=4 l=5216 cons: SET

**OUTPUT:**

> startnum: 7430
> 7567

But I would like achieve that in single line which i have tried in several ways, but could not do.
Any pointers/help appreciated.

```
startnum=$(cat $(openssl asn1parse -inform der -in $1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1) | cut -f1 -d:)

startnum=$(`cat $(openssl asn1parse -inform der -in $1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1)` | cut -f1 -d:)

startnum=$(cat $(`openssl asn1parse -inform der -in $1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1`) | cut -f1 -d:)

startnum=$(cat (`openssl asn1parse -inform der -in $1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1`) | cut -f1 -d:)

startnum=$(cat `openssl asn1parse -inform der -in $1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1` | cut -f1 -d:)

startnum=$(`openssl asn1parse -inform der -in $1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1` | cut -f1 -d:)

startnum=$($(`openssl asn1parse -inform der -in $1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1`) | cut -f1 -d:)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
echo startnum:"$(openssl asn1parse -inform der -in $1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1 | cut -f1 -d:)"
```

Comment: Well Thanks, that works like charm!!! I tried several sites but could not find anywhere(suitable) which can replace `cat` command like this and process.

Comment: I am actually interested in the second value than first, I can use array to store output and loop through, but is there any better way with little modification of above statement.

Comment: To ask a different question, ask a new question. You can always link to the previous one for context.