# putting output of a command into an array and extract particular position value

Tags: bash, shell-script

This question is with reference to other question which is asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657904/convert-multi-line-script-to-a-single-statement/657905?noredirect=1#comment1238395_657905)

I am trying to store the out put of below command into an array and extract the second value from
it, but could not get.

My output looks like storing the `cat` also in my array and also printing *No such file or directory* , which i dont understand how it is happening.

```
#!/bin/sh

array=($(cat $(openssl asn1parse -inform der -in $1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1 | cut -f1 -d:)))
echo ${array[1]}

# Below combinations also does not work
#echo startnum:"$(openssl asn1parse -inform der -in $1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1 | cut -f1 -d:)" > array
#array=($(cat "$(openssl asn1parse -inform der -in $1 | grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1 | cut -f1 -d:)"))
```

*OUTPUT*:

> cat: 7430: No such file or directory
> cat: 7567: No such file or directory

How can i change my script to extract second value in a single line?

Comment: You are not concatenating files, so there is no use for `cat` here. `array=$(openssl ... )`
What do you mean by "extract second value"? This is not explained in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the sample output is explained in the link provided in the post at section __contents of outfile.txt:__ , FYR i am pasting that here" `7430:d=7 hl=2 l= 11 prim: OBJECT :id-smime-aa-pattern
7567:d=7 hl=4 l=5216 cons: SET` here 7567 is the second value to extracted

Comment: Also, i dont want to store entire lines in the array, just the numbers which I am getting using `cut -f1 -d:`

Comment: why are you using `cat`?

Comment: By "extract second value", do you mean you want only the first field from the line **after** the line containing `id-smime-aa-pattern`?   if so, do you still want to capture the first field of the `id-smime-aa-pattern`?  because there's no point in using an array if that's what you want (unless there's more than one `id-smime-aa-pattern` line in your actual input data).

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
$ readarray -t array <<< $(openssl asn1parse -inform der -in "$1" | 
                             grep id-smime-aa-pattern -A 1 |
                             cut -f1 -d:)
```

or, using `awk` instead of `grep` and `cut`:

```bsh
readarray -t array <<< $(openssl asn1parse -inform der -in "$1" |
                           awk -F: '/id-smime-aa-pattern/ {print $1; getline; print $1}')
```

Given the sample input from your previous question, either of the above commands will result in $array containing:

```bsh
$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="7430" [1]="7567")
```

---

Or, if you only want the output from the line **after** `id-smime-aa-pattern`, you don't need to use an array:

```bsh
$ foo=$(openssl asn1parse -inform der -in "$1" |
          awk -F: '/id-smime-aa-pattern/ {getline; print $1}')
$ echo $foo
7567
```

Comment: Thanks @cas. I tested all your code, the last statement ( `foo=$(openssl asn1parse -inform der -in "$1" | awk -F: '/id-smime-aa-pattern/ {getline; print $1}')` ) , is good enough for me!! But, I don't understand how is it extracting number from my second line, could you pls elaborate what statement is doing that extraction/parsing.

Comment: In `readarray` solution two numbers are getting stored at `0th` location only, i tried printing `${array[1]}`, it dint print anything where as `${array[0]}` printed both values

Comment: `getline` tells awk to get the next line of input and split it into fields again.   See [4.10 Explicit Input with getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html) from the GNU awk manual.

Comment: if the version using `readarray` and `awk` is doing what you say, then the input is not what you said it was, not what's in `outfile.txt` in your earlier question.  I used that file for my testing, and the sample output I gave with `declare -p array` was copy-pasted directly from my terminal after piping outfile.txt into the awk script.

Comment: Yeah you are right. The `awk` solution is same for both (only extra in 1st one is, it prints both the number in first and second line). I am talking about the `grep` and `cut` solution. It stores both numbers in `0th` place

Comment: not on my system, using `outfile.txt` as input.  both the `awk` version and the `grep | cut` version produce **identical** results.